# Why SectionList onEndReached is not working?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

When I load my component `onEndReached` will be triggered one time before I scroll my `<SectionList />`, but when I scroll to bottom `onEndReached` won't be triggered any more.

Here is my code:

```
render (
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <SectionList
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink' }}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={false}
            onRefresh={() => console.log('refreshControl')}
            tintColor='gray'
          />
        }
        renderSectionHeader={this.sectionHeader}
        renderItem={this.renderSectionView}
        sections={reservations}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.05}
        onEndReached={(data) => {
         console.log('data', data); // { distanceFromEnd: -457 }
         console.log('onEndReached');
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray', height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth }} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
);
```

Here is my `<SectionList />` screen:
[image]

In my `<SectionList />` `refreshControl` is fine but `onEndReached` is not working, any one knows what happened ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a lot of people are experiencing the same. There is a suggestion to change the onEndReachedThreshold to value bigger that 0.05, for example: 0.5

Comment: Thanks for respond , but I try to set `0.5` is still not working

Comment: onEndReach works well when you have data fill up the screen. Try adding more data to screen

Comment: OK, so the problem is I have to fill up my screen first. Thanks, you help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
render (
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <SectionList
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink' }}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={false}
            onRefresh={() => console.log('refreshControl')}
            tintColor='gray'
          />
        }
        renderSectionHeader={this.sectionHeader}
        renderItem={this.renderSectionView}
        sections={reservations}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.05}
        onEndReached={(data) => {
         console.log('data', data); // { distanceFromEnd: -457 }
         console.log('onEndReached');
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'gray', height: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth }} />}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
);
```